# What equipment do I need to change a stage piano to play B3 organ?

Tags: midi

I have a 200 korg stage piano and would like to add the B3 organ and other piano sound to my keyboard. Can anyone tell me how that can be done? What equipment do I need to do this and can it be done without using the computer while playing?

Comment: Could you provide a link or a model number for exactly which piano this is? From Google I'm guessing SP200, but I don't want to presume.

Comment: You can typically add patches to most synths.  If you want a really good sounding organ, in my opinion, the only thing that comes close is Native Instruments B4.  But, that would require a computer.  Organ patches are definitely available for most synths, but they don't typically sound great.

Comment: @Brad: B4 is an abandonware now...but I think his question was more related to a specific hardware controler for the drawbars and/or a midi pedalboard

Comment: I have the NI B4 ... it's awsome. What about buying a Nord synth ( or module if they do one ) ... I havent used one but I think they're supposed to be the best hardware versions ... or at least at one time they were. I have a feeling you'd need a leslie to get the proper effect though but I'm not a keyboard player so just adding my 2c in case it helps. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oK4qxcHHwQE

Comment: ... if you're after a drawbar controller then this looks good http://www.soundonsound.com/news?NewsID=8100 and this http://jrrshop.com/catalog/ferrofish-b4000-hammond-module-p-6259.html